# Windows: Log which software do SSH outbound connections

Tags: windows, logs, ssh

It makes two times. I saw failed SSH connections from my PC to my NAS (that has an SSH server).

There are two options I can see:

- Someone spoofing my LAN ip address
- A malicious software on my PC tries to connect to my NAS

About the second option, does someone know a software to log all SSH outbound connections (that would include time, software, and maybe login).